# How can I store data on the backend script and use it in the content script of my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, backend, content-script, server-side-scripting

I want to know how my content script can communicate with the backend script.
I mean sending request from content script and get responce from backend script
based on request.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: @HaibaraAi Simple as that. I really wonder if people use search engines these days.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to message passing:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

When sending a message from content script to background script you'll simply use:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

When it's the other way around you'll need to specify the tab as well (please refer to the link above).